# treat php as html locally (opera)

Tags: php, html, opera

If I rename the index.php I am working on as index.html then it shows up ***exactly*** how I want it to in opera, locally. I am only editing html elements, I **do not care** if a few "<?php" appear in the lower left hand corner. This is **not** about running a server. The issue is the browser is showing it as plain text. No-one else will ever run *my* browser.

Uploading them to a server just to check spelling etc is not on, neither is rename, check, rename, upload, likewise running a server and then having to fiddle with the url on every page anyway is not exactly ideal either.

Is there a way to tell opera (or chrome, as second choices) to just locally treat .php as .html?

Answer (score 0):

GAH. Firefox upgraded when I quit and now it is working as I'd hoped. That'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** This is not something a browser gets to decide, but the webserver.

When you request a resource (e.g. `something.php`) from a web server, the webserver decides how it will process the request. This means that - in case of a "correct" server setup - php files will be executed and "only" the output is then sent back to the user's browser. i.e. the actual source code is not visible/available for the end user - this would even be a major security issue.

Of course, web servers might not have PHP installed or configured or enabled - and maybe this is your case. In this scenario, when the web server doesn't have any special "handler" for a given file extension, the file is returned as-is, with a given content-type, which is also configurable on the server level. i.e. you can tell to a web server what content type to return (in the form of a `Content-type` response header) for a resource with a given extension - if you have access to the server configuration, of course.
These content-types are most times predefined, e.g. for .html or .htm files the predefined content type is `text/html`, for .jpg it's `image/jpeg` and so on. **When .php files are executed, the default content type of the generated response is also `text/html`, but when the server does not handle php files in any "special way" and return them as-is, the often default content type will be `text-plain` - and this is why you see it as you see it.**

!!!You should never do this. If you want to write normal HTML, then get rid of any PHP code and name your files accordingly: something.html.